# Trying to add custom HTML to a lightbox

Tags: jquery, html, css, onclick, lightbox

I'm trying to implement a lightbox in my website. I followed [this](http://kyleschaeffer.com/development/lightbox-jquery-css/) tutorial, and it works fine. However, I want the lightbox to contain HTML code (such as  tags). The way that the tutorial showed forces the user to write what you want in the box inline with

`onclick="javascript:lightbox('stuff that's supposed to be in the box')"`.

How can I get it to read from another file? Or what is the best way of using HTML in the box? I would prefer to not have everything on one line.

http://jsfiddle.net/ytJaD/

Thanks!

Comment: If anyone cares I fixed this myself. I passed the ID of the parent <div> in the lightbox function. In the JavaScript code, I changed `$('#lightbox').append(insertContent);` to `$('#lightbox').append($(insertContent).show());`. Then I erased the two `$('#lightbox').empty();`. Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ytJaD/5/

Answer (score 1):

This is the code in the `lightbox()` function that puts HTML content in the box:

```
// insert HTML content
if(insertContent != null){
    $('#lightbox').append(insertContent);
}
```

All you need to do is modify or add to the javascript.

For example, do

```
onclick="javascript:lightbox('stuff <b>that's</b> supposed <a href="http://my.com">to be</a> in the box')"
```

to put bold parts in it and a link.

If you have a lot of text to put in you can do it this way:

```
onclick="javascript:lightbox('stuff <b>that's</b> ' +
'supposed <a href="http://my.com">to be</a> '
'in the box')"
```

Be sure to not lose spaces.

If you want the display to show more lines, use something like this:

```
onclick="javascript:lightbox('stuff <b>that's</b> supposed<br> <a href="http://my.com">to be</a> <br> in the box')"
```

Each `<br>` will result in a new line.

Its just HTML formatting.

Comment: So I just replace insertContent with the HTML code? What do I put in the brackets in the HTML section? (The onClick part). EDIT: I think I got it. Thanks!

Comment: yep! For example, do `onclick="javascript:lightbox('stuff <b>that's</b> supposed <a href="http://my.com">to be</a> in the box')"` to put bold parts in it and a link.

Comment: And there is no other way to do this? I was planning to customize the layout with divs, etc., and there would be a lot of code

Answer (score 0):

You have at least two options as I see. First you have to create an **XHR** (*XMLHttpRequest*) object and read the content from an external file to display in the lightbox.

The second opportunity to display content in an iframe or frame. So the lightbox will contain a frame, you specified.

Answer (score -1):

It doesn't appear lightbox supports that functionality out-of-the-box based on what I've read at:
http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/

But a good alternative is shadowbox.js found here:
http://www.shadowbox-js.com/

Documentation here:
http://www.shadowbox-js.com/usage.html

An example link once you have your libraries loaded properly:

```
<a href="myHTMLPage.html" rel="shadowbox;width=500;height=500;"></a>
```

Comment: I'm not using that plugin. I followed this: http://kyleschaeffer.com/development/lightbox-jquery-css/